# Is there a standard non-window exit event?

Tags: x11, xcb

I have an application that can have 1 or more active windows.

Currently I'm thinking of logic such that when all windows are closed, the application run-loop will exit gracefully and `main()` would `return 0`.

As a developer who has had experience with macOS, which has an application life-cycle defined separately from the visibility of windows, I wondered whether a similar concept exists for X11?

What I mean, is some general "Exit the application" event which would indicate the Window Manager/Desktop Environment wants you to close all windows and exit - similar to how macOS handles logging out or `Command-Q` in a GUI application.